# SOAP Response WCF Web service

Tags: wcf, soap

I am working on a SOAP based Web Service. My question is if it is possible to create a SOAP response in the format below

```
<tagname1>
<tag1> value1 </tag1>
<tag1> value2 </tag1>
</tagname1>
```

Specifically my doubt is if i can return 2 different values (ie value1 and value2 ) within two different tags which have same tag-names (ie tag1)

BTW i have created a class, and i am returning that class object as the response thus all fields of that class object appear as individual tags in the SOAP Response.

**UPDATE**

I found a partial solution. I have created an array element in my response class. I used the array element to store the list. When i returned the class object this was what i got -

```
<tagname .... >
<a:String> value1 </a:String>
<a:String> value2 </a:String>
<a:String> value3 </a:String>
</tagname>
```

any way i could replace "a:long" with an actual tagname ?

Comment: You can certainly do this, in different ways even, but the important detail is: *why* do you have the requirement of returning multiple `tag1` elements? Are you sure this is not an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Can you elaborate a bit on why you need this structure? (Note that you can edit the question to add details.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Jeroen !
I want to return a list of companies as a response from my web service. Would'nt this be the better way to do it ?

And could you please elaborate on how can such a response be generated ?

Answer (score 1):

SOAP is only a specific way of sending some data in some organized and structured way. You can send any format request which follows SOAP specs. The request should be a valid xml. The response is again formed by the server, in the same way. I'm not an expert in WCF. But SOAP i can tell you, the response should be a valid xml, nothing else. But mind this thing, who will be using the response?, If you only use it for internal purpose, you dont have any problems with any representation. But if you plan to expose it as some public service, make your response meaningful.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply !
yes we are creating this service for internal purposes. I wanted to return multiple values. All the values signify and represent the same thing. I don't want to create a multiple tags but one single tag and return multiple values. 

Is there anyway in which this can be implemented ?

i hope i have made doubts clear

Thanks !

Comment: an example of this situation could be - 

    <companylist>
    <company>adidas</company>
    <company>nike</company>
    <company>reebok</company>
    </companylist>